# Write activity alias in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Can any one please help me that how can I write activity alias in xamarin?
If I try it gives me 
`Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED Error.`

Comment: How did you try? When do you receive this message? We need more information.

Comment: I'm trying same sample on this website, it is working in native android ,but not in xamarin.
https://derivedcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/showing-badge-or-count-in-android-app-icon/

I'm not getting why it is downvoted

Comment: Please include example of your manifest file. Downvotes are probably because you need to provide more details to help people assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write activity tag in manifest for Xamarin.
Just add activity alias in manifest.
If your target activity in alias is

```
android:targetActivity="com.example.study.MainActivity"
```

then 
add 
    `Activity[(name="com.example.study.MainActivity")]`
in MainActivity.cs class.